# Show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-it^2}dt=(1-i)(\frac{\pi}{2})^{0.5}?$

Tags: integration

Show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-it^2}dt=(1-i)(\frac{\pi}{2})^{0.5}?$ This is in my formula sheet but I'm intrigued as to how it is proved?

Comment: This is obtained using the imaginary error function $$\int e^{-it^2}dt=-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{-1} \sqrt{\pi } \,\text{erfi}\left((-1)^{3/4} t\right)$$

Comment: See [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-it^{2}}dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos\left(t^{2}\right)dt-i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin\left(t^{2}\right)dt
 .$$ Now we have $$\int\cos\left(t^{2}\right)dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}t\right)+cost
 $$where $C\left(*\right)
 $ is the Fresnel C integral and $$\int\sin\left(t^{2}\right)dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}t\right)+cost$$
 is the Fresnel S integral. Using the special values $$C\left(\infty\right)=S\left(\infty\right)=\frac{1}{2}
 $$ and $$C\left(-\infty\right)=S\left(-\infty\right)=-\frac{1}{2}
 $$ your claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

for $R \gt 0$ define $A,O,B$ as the points $(R,0),(0,0),(R\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-R\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ which we connect by straight lines $AO,OB$ and a circular arc of radius $R$ joining $B$ to$A$

then (since the integrand) has no poles in the sector $AOB$ we know that
$$
\int_A^O + \int_O^B +\int_B^A e^{-it^2}dt= 0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{R \to \infty}\int_A^Oe^{-it^2}dt = -\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-it^2}dt
$$
if the integral on the circular arc tends to zero (see note*) as $R$ approaches $\infty$. the integral along $OB$ can be obtained via the substitution
$$
t=\frac{(1-i)}{\sqrt{2}} s
$$
which gives
$$
\int_O^B e^{-it^2}dt = \frac{(1-i)}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-s^2} ds = \frac{1-i}2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}2}
$$
from which the required result follows

- **note**
  the gory details would not enliven this particular discussion, but the method is straightforward - split the arc into a long and a short piece separated by the  point whose argument is $-\sin^{-1}(R^{-\frac32})$